# How to correctly use querySkuDetailsAsync?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to use the billing library and I am getting info from the official Android Developer site [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient). But I am finding a lot of trouble. Mainly compiling problems. It looks like that documentation is not completed. When I started following step by step I had to search for a lot of extra information. Now I am stuck trying to do querySkuDetailsAsync() 
This is my code:

```
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
                skuList.add("sp_hide_ads_year_01");
                SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

                billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                //*** I want to Continue here ***
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });
```

The compiler (Android Studio) says:

> 'onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult, List)' in 'Anonymous
>   class derived from
>   com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener' clashes with
>   'onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult, List)' in
>   'com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener'; both
>   methods have erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I have no idea what this means. any help here?

By the way, I use

> implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the line:

```
public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList)
```

for this one, and everything compiled:

```
public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails> skuDetailsList)
```